# Creating Applications With E4

Tags: eclipse-plugin, e4

I'm in the process of learning how to live with E4 and now I'm struggling with the plug-in structure.

In our "normal" E3 applications we had multiple modules like:

- Module A - Auditing
- Module B - Basic functionality
- Module D - Document management
- Module U - User management

And then we had multiple applications build from them:

- Customer 1 - Modules A, B
- Customer 2 - Modules B, D
- Customer 3 - Modules A, B, D, U

Because these applications had completely different use-cases, the layout was a little different for each of them.

In E4 however, the dependency structure seems to be flipped around. The "base" is now the application (the plug-in with the *Application.e4xmi*), and modules register themselves.

So in the example, module B would somehow have to registered itself for the ID's of the applications of Customer 1, 2 and 3... which is either impossible or just plain stupid.

Are there any best practices for creating normal applications with E4? Or to flip the dependency back around?

The best we can come up with is to have a dummy application somewhere in our base and then do everything programmatically. Which at least would prevent us from using the horrid Application Editor, but with the "no exception no log" policy of E4 I fear we'll quickly create unmaintainable code.

So any ideas on how that's supposed to work?

Comment: Plugins can use the `org.eclipse.e4.workbench.model` extension point to contribute 'fragments' to the basic UI defined in the Application.e4xmi

Comment: @greg-449 In our case the application is the most top-level component, so the modules don't know the specific application ID (yet). Also the plug-ins cannot and should not decide where views, editors and commands are displayed.

Comment: You can avoid specifying the application id by using an XPath expression in the extend element id field such as `xpath:/`

Comment: @greg-449 Can you elaborate? I tried all kinds of XPath expressions as "Extended Element ID" and all it does is to break the _fragment.e4xmi_.

Comment: The only one I use is `xpath:/` which should be exactly the same as specifying the application id. The XPath is the path in the Application.e4xmi file (which is just XML). Note it must start with `xpath:` to be recognised as XPath so `xpath:/` is the XPath expression `/` (the root element) (see also [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse4Modularity/article.html))

Comment: @greg-449 It works using an XML editor. So what about parts? They need a part stack to open, and there is no possible way an independent bundle knows of an arbitrary ID the application is going to use later on.